# interactive tooltip library

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I am looking for a tooltip library that can do the following:

1. "cling to" or "point to" something rather then following the mouse around
2. allows me to move my mouse over to it and interact with it
3. disappears when my mouse leaves the element that fired the tooltip or leaves the tooltip box
4. Allows me to dynamically create the contents of the tooltip on the fly

A perfect example of what I'm looking for is the box that pops up in the gmail chat when you hover over a person's name, you can then go and interact with that tooltip.

I have experience with both jquery and prototype so if something is based off of either of those I'm cool with that.

thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this using jQuery UI Tooltip. It has good documentation and lot of support up here.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Popovers is a good solution; it's a jQuery plugin, and although it's shown on the click event you could easily change this to display on hover.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers